# Send JavaScript array to database using submit

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms

I have looked at some other question regarding sending javascript arrays to php so save the data in database.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
<input type='submit' id="save" value='Spara' onclick='sendFunc()'>
<script>
var rad = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

function sendFunc() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "/insert.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {myArray : rad}
  });
}
</script>
</form>
}
```

and in insert.php

```
<?php
$array = $_POST['myArray'];
echo $array;
?>
```

i did expect to see my array rad on the insert page.
What did i do wrong?

Comment: _"i did expect to see my array rad on the insert page"_ - _where_ are you _looking_ for it?

Comment: well, as i understand this, i navigate to insert,php sending 'rad' as myArray using POST. then in insert.php i check post variable myArray but it aint containing the array 'rad'

Answer (score 0):

Try to add preventDefault and close your brackets properly:

```
function sendFunc(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/insert.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {myArray : rad}
    });
}
```

Comment: sry for missing bracket, copy paste error. updated the question.
but preventDefault didn't give me any information from $_POST['myArray']; in insert.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent from refreshing page by return false on your click function ...

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
<input type='submit' id="save" value='Spara' onclick='return sendFunc();'>
<script>
var rad = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

function sendFunc() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "/insert.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {myArray : rad}
});  
 return false;
}
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: When trying this i don't end up in insert.php.

Answer (score 0):

required jquery.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#save").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/insert.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {myArray : rad}
        }); 
    }).done(function(data){
        $("body").html(data);
    });
})
```

or you can edit your function()

```
function sendFunc() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/insert.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {myArray : rad}
    }).done(function(data){
        $("body").html(data);
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i've got to the insert.php using this in function sendFunc() but $_POST['myArray']; dont return any value.

Comment: you clicked submit, this form send data with " form action " not send by Ajax.